# Distribute data between MongoDb Shards

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a development environment with two shards, one configuration server and one router as illustrated below. I have a sharded database "mydb2" and a sharded colleciton "mycollection2". When I insert data to mycollection2 from router, it is inserting to s1. And next time s2. And s1 again and so on. How can I insert data to both two shards same time. I am using MongoDb 4.2.3

[image]

**UPDATE:** I added s1 and s2 to the same zone. I declared a shard key range. But nothing changed. I insert data to the collection with ranged shard key, bu data is not distributed.

Comment: What do you mean by _"How can I insert data to both two shards same time."_? The data is written to either of the shards based upon the shard key value. It is correct that if you insert a document into to the sharded collection, it will write to _only_ one shard. See the image from [Ranged shard key](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/ranged-sharding/#shard-key-selection) document.

Comment: _"How can I insert data to both two shards same time."_: When multiple client applications insert documents with varied shard key values, then _it is likely_ that documents will be inserted on both shards _at the same time_.